# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cherrypy'

Tags: python

I'm trying to install pgwatch2 in my server and during the many things that needed to be installed it also includes installing a few pythong modules.

I'm using python 3.6 and I installed the modules localy (downloaded the tar files) and used the next command  to install the modules :

```
pip3.6 install tar_file
```

When I verify that everything is installed I dont get any error (the first one is cherrypy):

```
[webpy]# pip3.6 install -r requirements.txt 
Requirement already satisfied: cherrypy in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied: influxdb in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cherrypy->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied: cheroot>=6.2.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cherrypy->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied: portend>=2.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cherrypy->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from jinja2->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from influxdb->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from influxdb->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.17.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from influxdb->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied: backports.functools_lru_cache in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cheroot>=6.2.4->cherrypy->-r     requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied: more_itertools>=2.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cheroot>=6.2.4->cherrypy->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied: tempora>=1.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from portend>=2.1.1->cherrypy->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.17.0->influxdb->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.17.0->influxdb->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.17.0->influxdb->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.17.0->influxdb->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied: jaraco.functools>=1.20 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tempora>=1.8->portend>=2.1.1->cherrypy->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

pip version :

```
 pip3.6 --version
 pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

However when I run a python script as one of the steps of the installation I'm getting the next error :

```
[webpy]# python3.6 web.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web.py", line 9, in <module>
    import cherrypy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cherrypy'
```

Any idea what else can I check?

Comment: You probably have multiple versions of Python installed. Try `python3.6 -m pip list` and verify that `cherrypi` is in the list. If not, run `python3.6 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: python3.6 -m pip list returned nothing. python3.6 -m pip install CherryPy-16.0.2.tar.gz 
Processing ./CherryPy-16.0.2.tar.gz
Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution.
Please install setuptools. But I have setuptools installed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following to find out what python installation `python3.6` is using:

```
(base) C:\Users\felix>python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Users\\felix\\Anaconda3\\python.exe'
```

Now you probably get another path than the one that pip uses `/usr/lib/python3.6`.

There are two options:

### 1. Run the python interpreter that pip uses

`/usr/lib/python3.6 web.py`

### 2. Install your packages into the python installation that gets invoked by `python3.6`

`python3.6 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: But As you can see in my main post all modules were installed in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages. 
 When I run only python it uses python 2.7.5. It seems that when I used /usr/bin/python3.6 web.py it worked but without the full path it didnt work. Anyway thanks !

Comment: How to do it for python2.7

Comment: use `python` instead of `python3.6`